Why does my garage door remote close the door inconsistently?
When using an opener my (rental property) garage door will lift open without fail but only lowers on occasion. It’s an old door and doesn’t have safety sensors. The remote is a model 390LMD21V and the motor is a Sears/Craftsman model 41A3066.
Both the remote and motor use dip switches and they are matched up as they should be. They both do not have a “learn button”. The door will open from 30-40 feet away every time but you could be inches away from it with the remote and it regularly won’t close. There is also a button on the wall to open/close and this works without any issues.

A common issue is RF interference with LED bulbs near the garage door opener.  If you have LED bulbs nearby, (or even in the opener itself), take them out temporarily and see if your remote works then.  If so, then look for LED bulbs that are designed to be "garage door friendly", and they won't put out nearly the RF interference.

Why would RF interference only affect lowering?

Usually a door when closed, has been closed for a while so associated lighting has timed out and turned off.  If it's open and someone is trying to close it, there's a higher chance of it having just been opened and so the controlled lights would still be on, causing interference.

There are no LEDS bulbs inside the garage or on the motor itself.
